# Как сделать рендер элемента при определенном условии?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

После того как пользователь залогиниться, должна открываться страница с его профилем, иначе открывается форма с логином.Информация о том залогинился ли пользователь находится this.state.user

```
 render() {
    return (
        <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/registration" component={RegistrForm} />
        <Route path="/id"   render={this.state.user ? (<MainPage />) : (<Login />)} />
        </Router>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**1 вариант:**

Если пишешь функциональные компоненты, то есть хук useHistory

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Внутри компонента (где происходит авторизация, как я понимаю, это компонент Login) вызови:

```
const history = useHistory();
```

И при успешном входе вызывай:

```
history.push('/куда_надо_урл')
```

**2 вариант:**

Делаешь обертку для роутов PrivateRoute, например:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  const user = {
    isFakeAuth: true,
  };

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        user.isFakeAuth ? (<Component {...props} />) : (<Redirect to="/" />)
      }
    />
  );
};
```

И вместо обычного Route оборачиваешь те роуты в PrivateRoute, куда могуть войти только авторизованные пользователи